# Replace JavaScript confirm alert with bootbox.js confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I am not quite understanding how to implement [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/#examples) to replace my standard javascript confirm alert popups and need some assistance. I have read some threads and the docs, but just cannot quite get it right.

I currently have this button/link that holds the record number in my template:

```
<a href="{% url overseas_experience_details_duplicate overseas_experience_detail.id %}" onclick="if(confirmDuplicate())showProgressAnimation();else return false;">{% trans "Duplicate" %}</a>
```

this calls the current js function that I want to replace with bootbox.js:

```
function confirmDuplicate() {
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
}
```

If the OK option is checked, the record is duplicated (with the show progress animation displaying while the record is duplicated). If the CANCEL option is selected, then nothing happens.

I have used the following code to implement the bootbox alert, but I am not sure how to return the bootbox OK confirmation which will then duplicate the record.

**bootbox.js**

```
function confirmDuplicate() {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result == true) {

        // not too sure what to insert here to return the bootbox confirm();

    }
});
```

**Some valid suggestions would be appreciated**

**UPDATE TO QUESTION**

I now have the bootbox confirm pop up displaying, but I cannot return the "true" or "false" confirmation result. Here is my newer code:

```
function confirmDuplicate() {
    bootbox.confirm({
        callback: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am frustrated that I cannot return the result to duplicate the record.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why are you writing your javascript in your html? I see you have jquery as a tag in the question, if you would actually use it it will turn out as a pretty simple task

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
<a href="whatever" onclick="return myConfirm(this.href)">....

myConfirm = function(url) {
    bootbox.confirm("sure?", function(okay) {
        if(okay)
             location.href = url;
    });
    return false;
}
```

You cannot obtain `bootbox.confirm` results immediately, therefore return `false` from the handler to prevent the link from being followed and carry out the required action in the callback function.

Comment: I have tried your example, but still cannot get the return back to the button that was clicked!

Comment: @user3354539: that's the point: you cannot return from a callback. You're supposed to _do_ something in the callback, not to return.

Comment: OK I can now see what I was doing incorrectly, but I still do not know how to write the js code in the callback to trigger the duplicate href in the hyperlink as detailed in the question above: **<a href="{% url overseas_experience_details_duplicate overseas_experience_detail.id %}" onclick="if(confirmDuplicate())showProgressAnimation();else return false;">{% trans "Duplicate" %}</a>**

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment to your question, here's a non-obstrusive jquery version:

```
$('.your-link-class').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //this would be equivalent to the return false in your code
   var self = this;
   bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
       if (result) {
           // Here you have access to the jquery object of your link with $(self)
           // and you can do stuff like, for example:
           var clone = $(self).clone();
           clone.insertAfter($(self));
       }
    });
});
```

And a demo (not: in the demo I'm using traditional prompts instead because I don't have loaded the bootbox source):

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still am unable to return the confirmation result.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isConfirm(message, elem) {

    bootbox.confirm(message, function (result) {
        if (result)
            window.location.href = elem;
    });

    return false;
}
<a href='@Url.Action("DeleteAction", "Admin", new { id = Model.ActionObj.id })' onclick="javascript: return isConfrm('Are you sure you want to delete this action?', this)">  Delete </a>
```

use this for function:

```
function isConfirm(message, elem) {
    bootbox.confirm(message, function (result) {
        if (result)
            window.location.href = elem;
    });

    return false;
}
```